# Unable to create a constant value of type ''. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context. linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I'm getting this exception, Unable to create a constant value of type 'XXX'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

i'm trying to do a sub query in a linq experession, 
i'm using 2 data sgources the dbContext to get all data anda list of languages returned from a service.

```
objData = (from s in db.Search
  let lan = langList
  //join l in db.Language on s.LanguageId equals l.Id
  join u in db.User on s.UserId equals u.Id
  where u.Id == (UserId == Guid.Empty ? u.Id : UserId)
        && s.isActive == true
        && s.SearchId == SearchId
  select new userModel.Search()
  {
      Language = (from l in lan
                  join sl in db.Search on l.Id equals sl.LanguageId
                  where (sl.Id == s.Id || sl.SearchId == s.SearchId) && sl.isActive == true
                  select new userModel.Language
                  {
                      Id = l.Id,
                      Name = l.Name,
                      Code = l.Code,
                      isActive = l.isActive,
                      CreatedAt = l.CreatedAt,
                      UpdatedAt = l.UpdatedAt,
                      DeletedAt = l.DeletedAt
                  }).ToList()
  }).ToList();
```

Comment: Is it at `u.Gender`?

Comment: You'll need to narrow down where the error is (or give the type that the error message specifies).  Start with a simple query and add more peices until the error appears.

Comment: i commented the subquery and works fine...

Comment: @RobsonGmack: Which subquery? What line breaks it?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior this subquery
Language = (from l in lan
                  join sl in db.Search on l.Id equals sl.LanguageId ...

Comment: Please make a little more effort to narrow this down to a minimal example. Remove as many lines as possible to produce the same error. Also, the name of the class that you replaced with "XXX" is probably a good clue, which you should include if possible.

Comment: Solved it,
first i populate the search list without the language, next i populate the language in a for each.